# What are the ways one can control spacing between nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I have 4 nodes, one on top of each other, I would like to know the different ways to control the spacing between the nodes. I already know a few:

- `\node[...below=1cm of xyz]`
- `\tikzstyle[...node distance = 2cm]`
- `\tikzstyle[...inner sep = 2pt]`

Could someone provide me with a more comprehensive list of options.

In this case, specifically, I have a picture like so (work in progress)

[image: Sample Tikz Picture]

I want to be able to control the big blue box so it is closer to the left and right borders than it is to the top and bottom. I also want to control the synapses so they move down such that synapse 3 is closer to the bottom than synapse 0 is to the top. I basically want full control of all four paddings. Here is the TikZ code used to generate the above image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
  simulator engine/.style={fill=black!10,rounded corners,inner sep=20pt},
  topology/.style={rounded corners,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,inner sep=3pt},
  neuron/.style={fill=blue!10,draw=blue,rounded corners,inner sep=15pt},
  synapse/.style={draw=red!75,fill=red!20,rounded corners,inner sep=5pt},
  empty synapse/.style={draw=blue!10,rounded corners,inner sep=5pt}
  ]
  \node[simulator engine] (simulatorEngine) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[topology] (topology1) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node [neuron] (neuron1-1)  {
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue] (synapse1-1-0) {$\text{Synapse}_{0}$};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-1-0] (synapse1-1-1) {$\text{Synapse}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-1-1] (synapse1-1-2) {$\text{Synapse}_{2}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.2cm of synapse1-1-2] (synapse1-1-e) {\ldots};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-1-e] (synapse1-1-3) {$\text{Synapse}_{3}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [neuron,draw=blue,right=0.2cm of neuron1-1] (neuron1-2) {
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue] (synapse1-2-0) {$\text{Synapse}_{0}$};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-2-0] (synapse1-2-1) {$\text{Synapse}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-2-1] (synapse1-2-2) {$\text{Synapse}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-2-2] (synapse1-2-3) {$\text{Synapse}_{3}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [neuron,draw=blue,right=0.2cm of neuron1-2] (neuron1-3) {
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue] (synapse1-3-0) {$\text{Synapse}_{0}$};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-3-0] (synapse1-3-1) {$\text{Synapse}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-3-1] (synapse1-3-2) {$\text{Synapse}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,draw=blue,below=0.1cm of synapse1-3-2] (synapse1-3-3) {$\text{Synapse}_{3}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };

          \node [black,below] at (neuron1-1.north)  {$\text{Neuron}_{0}$};
          \node [black,below] at (neuron1-2.north)  {$\text{Neuron}_{1}$};
          \node [black,below] at (neuron1-3.north)  {$\text{Neuron}_{2}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };

    \end{tikzpicture}
    };

    \node [black,below] at (simulatorEngine.north) {Simulator Engine};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just some formatting advice: instead of `$\text{Synapse}_{1}$` you could write `Synapse$_1$`

Comment: You can use `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` to get the sides closer to the content than the top/bottom. To get control over all four is (I believe) a lot harder. What you could do for the synapses is increase the `outer ysep` for the top node to distance it further from the top. You would have to find some combination of these values to get what you want then. I don't know of an easier way to really control the padding. You can also have a look at the `fit` library for some automatic sizing.

Comment: @TomBombadil: I agree that's fewer keystrokes but I think the OP's code is more semantic.  IMO adding a subscript makes "Synapse" a symbol, which means it belongs in math mode.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Hmm, but the node is a priori not in math mode. Putting it in math mode and then escaping it again via `\text{}` seems a little bit off to me. Thats the kind of "double negative" the math fan in me is afraid of ;)

Comment: @TomBombadil right or wrong, I did not know you could do that with subscripts in math mode. Thank You

Answer (score 25, accepted):

control spacing between nodes ? good question for an exam about tikz !

**1. to be or not to be a node ?**

I suppose for the next part of the answer that the reasons to use "node" are fine (the first reason is to display some text). I think that you cannot consider that `inner
    sep` is a way to control spacing between nodes.
    For example, when `line width` grows, the line recovers `inner sep`.
    `inner sep` is a part of the object  `node`.  The two important
    parts of a node are the body (here the text) and the shape. The
    dimensions of the shape depends of the dimensions of the body, the
    value of  `inner sep`, the value of `line width`. The definition of a node gives anchors. It's possible to use them to place the nodes.

**2. Same dimensions ?**

Before placing nodes, you need to know if all the nodes
    have the same shape with the same dimensions. In this case, it's
    possible to place automatically the nodes.

**3. Absolute position**

In the next example, I use absolute coordinates. It's interesting because, you can apply a scale option in this case. You need to give the exact dimensions of each node. The distance between the two last lists is 1.25 cm (I use a scale option). I get it with `($(\n.east)+(1,0)$)`. `xshift=1cm` is another possibility but in this case, the scale option doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[]{fourier} % I need to use €    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document} 

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \n [count=\i from 0] in {A,B,C,D}
{\node [draw,minimum width =2cm,minimum height=2ex] at (0,\i*1 cm) {Text \n};  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.25]
  \foreach \n [count=\i from 0] in {a,b,c,d}
{\node [draw,minimum width =2cm,minimum height=2ex] (\n) at (0,\i*1 cm) {Text \n};} 
  \foreach \n [count=\i from 0] in {a,b,c,d} 
{\node [draw,minimum width =2cm,
       minimum height=2ex,anchor=west] (\n) at at ($(\n.east)+(1,0)$) {Text \n\i};}  
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

**4. relative position with anchors or with the positioning library**

The letter is placed at (0,0) but an anchor is used to place one corner at the origin. Then a stamp is placed relatively at the upper right corner. The second stamp is placed relatively to the first. `left=2mm of stamp1` replaces `anchor=north east,shift={(-2mm,0mm)}` (see the comment line).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[]{fourier} % I need to use €    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw,scale=1.25] 
  \tikzset{stamp/.style={fill=blue!20,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1.4cm,align=center}}
  \node[fill=lightgray!15,minimum width=10cm,minimum height=6cm,align=left,anchor=south west] (letter) at (0,0)  {Mr AlterMundus\\Paris\\France};
  \node [stamp,anchor=north east,shift={(-2mm,-2mm)}] (stamp1) at (letter.north east){2€};
  %\node [stamp,anchor=north east,shift={(-2mm,0mm)}] (stamp2) at (stamp1.north west){2€}; 
  \node[stamp,left=2mm of stamp1] {1€};
\end{tikzpicture}       
\end{document}
```

[image]

**5. relative position  with the positioning library with(out) grid option**

It's possible to use the positioning library to place nodes relatively to their centers and not to their borders. In the next example, i use the two possibilities

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[]{fourier} % I need to use €    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=draw,scale=1.25] 
  \tikzset{card/.style={fill=blue!20,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1.4cm,align=center}}
  \draw[fill=green!15!black!20,minimum width=10cm,minimum height=6cm,align=left,anchor=south west]   (0,0) rectangle (8,4) coordinate[pos=.5](O);
  \node [above=.5cm,card,xshift=1cm] (card1) at (O){\Huge \textbf{V}};
  \node[on grid,card,left=.6cm of card1] (card2){\Huge \textbf{D}};
  \node[on grid,card,left=.6cm of card2] (card3){\Huge \textbf{R}};  
  \node[on grid,card,left=.6cm of card3] (card4){\Huge \textbf{A}}; 
  \node [below=.5cm,,card,xshift=2cm] (card1) at (O){\Huge \textbf{V}};
  \node[card,left=.5cm of card1] (card2){\Huge \textbf{D}};
  \node[card,left=.5cm of card2] (card3){\Huge \textbf{R}};  
  \node[card,left=.5cm of card3] (card4){\Huge \textbf{A}};   
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**node distance**

This is useful only to place nodes (relative method) without to precise the distance but it's a length and not a "way" to place node.

**Conclusion** If you need to control the spacing between nodes, you can use the positioning library ( with(out) "on grid" option, center to center or border to border) or you can also use the anchors and absolute coordinates.

Answer (score 9):

This is not directly answering your question but gives a handle for the control over 4 `sep` values. I used `matrix` to align synapses but pushed the topology and the simulator boxes to background layers using the `fit` library. After that you can shift, scale, or give `minimum heigth` requirements to override the rectangles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,matrix}
\tikzset{simulator engine/.style={fill=black!10,
                          rounded corners,
                          inner sep=20pt,
                          label={[inner sep=1ex,yshift=-5ex,anchor=north]90:Simulator Engine}},
            topology/.style={rounded corners,
                           draw=blue!50,
                           fill=blue!20,
                           thick,
                           inner sep=3pt},
            neuron/.style={fill=blue!10,
                           draw=blue,
                           rounded corners,
                           inner sep=15pt},
            synapse/.style={draw=red!75,
                           fill=red!20,
                           rounded corners,
                           inner sep=5pt},
            empty synapse/.style={draw=none,
                           fill=none,
                           rounded corners,
                           inner sep=5pt}
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{simulator}
\pgfdeclarelayer{topology}
\pgfsetlayers{simulator,topology,main}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]

\matrix (N0) [neuron,inner sep=3mm,
                     matrix of nodes,
                     nodes={synapse,draw=blue},
                     row sep=1mm,
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     outer sep=2mm]{
|[label={[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0]90:Neuron$_0$}]| Synapse$_1$ \\
Synapse$_2$ \\
Synapse$_3$ \\
| [empty synapse] | $\vdots$ \\
Synapse$_4$ \\
};


\matrix (N1) at (3,0) [neuron,inner sep=3mm,
                     matrix of nodes,
                     nodes={synapse,draw=blue},
                     row sep=1mm,
                     nodes in empty cells,
                     outer sep=2mm]{
|[label={[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0]90:Neuron$_0$}]| Synapse$_1$ \\
Synapse$_2$ \\
Synapse$_3$ \\
Synapse$_4$ \\
};


\begin{pgfonlayer}{topology}
\node[fit=(N0)(N1),topology,xshift=2mm,yshift=-1.5mm,minimum height=8cm] (T) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{simulator}
\node[fit=(N0)(N1)(T),simulator engine,xshift=2mm,yshift=2mm] (S) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play around with the `shift`s and `minimum height` keys in the last two layers to see their effect. (Set them to zero initially to see the original alignment)

Answer (score 6):

I figured out how to do it, and I thought it might be useful to anyone else who is having the same problem. Note, the other answers are just as valid, if not more so. Also, this is in no way perfect, and there is a great deal of cheating going on here.

**End Result:**

[image: Properly Aligned Diagram]

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,calc,shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,
  simulator engine/.style={%
      thick,
      fill=blue!10,
      draw=black!75,
      rounded corners,
      inner ysep=4pt,
      inner xsep=4pt
  },
  empty simulator engine/.style={%
      fill=black!10,
      rounded corners,
      inner ysep=20pt,
      inner xsep=5pt
  },
  topology/.style={%
      general shadow={%
        shadow scale=1,
        shadow xshift=0.75ex,
        shadow yshift=0.75ex,
        opacity=0.75,
        fill=black!50,
        every shadow
      },
      rounded corners,
      thick,
      draw=blue!90,
      fill=blue!35,
      thick,
      inner ysep=2pt,
      inner xsep=2pt
  },
  empty topology/.style={%
      fill=blue!10,
      inner ysep=0pt,
      inner xsep=0pt
  },
  neuron/.style={%
      general shadow={%
        shadow scale=1,
        shadow xshift=0.5ex,
        shadow yshift=0.5ex,
        opacity=0.75,
        fill=black!50,
        every shadow
      },
      thick,
      fill=blue!10,
      draw=blue!75,
      rounded corners,
      inner ysep=2pt,
      inner xsep=2pt,
      minimum width=0.5cm
  },
  empty neuron/.style={%
      fill=blue!35,
      inner sep=0pt,
      minimum width=0.05cm
  },
  synapse/.style={%
      general shadow={%
        shadow scale=1,
        shadow xshift=0.5ex,
        shadow yshift=0.5ex,
        opacity=0.75,
        fill=black!50,
        every shadow
      },
      draw=red!75,
      thick,
      fill=red!20,
      rounded corners,
      inner ysep=3pt,
      inner xsep=3pt,
      minimum width=0.5cm
  },
  empty synapse/.style={%
      draw=blue!10,
      rounded corners,
      inner sep=1pt
  }
  ]
  \node[simulator engine] (simulatorEngine) {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[empty topology] (simulatorEngine-label) {Simulator Engine};
      \node[topology,below=0.3cm of simulatorEngine-label,xshift=-4.3cm] (topology1) {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node[empty neuron] (topology1-label) {$\text{Topology}_{1}$};
          \node [neuron,below=0.3cm of topology1-label,xshift=-1.6cm] (neuron1-1)  {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapse1-1-label) {$\text{N}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapse1-1-label] (synapse1-1-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-1-0] (synapse1-1-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-1-1] (synapse1-1-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-1-2] (synapse1-1-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-1-e] (synapse1-1-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuron1-1] (neuron1-2) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapse1-2-label) {$\text{N}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapse1-2-label] (synapse1-2-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-2-0] (synapse1-2-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-2-1] (synapse1-2-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-2-2] (synapse1-2-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-2-e] (synapse1-2-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuron1-2] (neuron1-3) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapse1-3-label) {$\text{N}_{3}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapse1-3-label] (synapse1-3-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-3-0] (synapse1-3-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-3-1] (synapse1-3-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-3-2] (synapse1-3-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-3-e] (synapse1-3-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [empty neuron,right=0.1cm of neuron1-3] (neuron1-e) {\ldots};
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuron1-e] (neuron1-l) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapse1-l-label) {$\text{N}_{l}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapse1-l-label] (synapse1-l-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-l-0] (synapse1-l-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-l-1] (synapse1-l-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-l-2] (synapse1-l-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse1-l-e] (synapse1-l-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };

      \node[topology,right=0.3cm of topology1] (topology2) {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node[empty neuron] (topology2-label) {$\text{Topology}_{2}$};
          \node [neuron,below=0.3cm of topology2-label,xshift=-1.6cm] (neuron2-1)  {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapse2-1-label) {$\text{N}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapse2-1-label] (synapse2-1-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-1-0] (synapse2-1-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-1-1] (synapse2-1-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-1-2] (synapse2-1-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-1-e] (synapse2-1-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuron2-1] (neuron2-2) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapse2-2-label) {$\text{N}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapse2-2-label] (synapse2-2-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-2-0] (synapse2-2-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-2-1] (synapse2-2-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-2-2] (synapse2-2-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-2-e] (synapse2-2-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuron2-2] (neuron2-3) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapse2-3-label) {$\text{N}_{3}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapse2-3-label] (synapse2-3-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-3-0] (synapse2-3-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-3-1] (synapse2-3-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-3-2] (synapse2-3-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-3-e] (synapse2-3-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [empty neuron,right=0.1cm of neuron2-3] (neuron2-e) {\ldots};
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuron2-e] (neuron2-l) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapse2-l-label) {$\text{N}_{l}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapse2-l-label] (synapse2-l-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-l-0] (synapse2-l-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-l-1] (synapse2-l-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-l-2] (synapse2-l-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapse2-l-e] (synapse2-l-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };

      \node [empty topology,right=0.3cm of topology2] (topology-e) {\ldots};

      \node[topology,right=0.1cm of topology-e] (topologyk) {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node[empty neuron] (topologyk-label) {$\text{Topology}_{k}$};
          \node [neuron,below=0.3cm of topologyk-label,xshift=-1.6cm] (neuronk-1)  {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapsek-1-label) {$\text{N}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapsek-1-label] (synapsek-1-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-1-0] (synapsek-1-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-1-1] (synapsek-1-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-1-2] (synapsek-1-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-1-e] (synapsek-1-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuronk-1] (neuronk-2) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapsek-2-label) {$\text{N}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapsek-2-label] (synapsek-2-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-2-0] (synapsek-2-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-2-1] (synapsek-2-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-2-2] (synapsek-2-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-2-e] (synapsek-2-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuronk-2] (neuronk-3) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapsek-3-label) {$\text{N}_{3}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapsek-3-label] (synapsek-3-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-3-0] (synapsek-3-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-3-1] (synapsek-3-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-3-2] (synapsek-3-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-3-e] (synapsek-3-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [empty neuron,right=0.1cm of neuronk-3] (neuronk-e) {\ldots};
          \node [neuron,right=0.1cm of neuronk-e] (neuronk-l) {%
              \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [empty synapse] (synapsek-l-label) {$\text{N}_{l}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.3cm of synapsek-l-label] (synapsek-l-0) {$\text{S}_{1}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-l-0] (synapsek-l-1) {$\text{S}_{2}$};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-l-1] (synapsek-l-2) {$\text{S}_{3}$};
                  \node [empty synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-l-2] (synapsek-l-e) {\vdots};
                  \node [synapse,below=0.1cm of synapsek-l-e] (synapsek-l-n) {$\text{S}_{n}$};
              \end{tikzpicture}
          };
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```